# Are there any JS touch-screen controller library?

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I made a little canvas game. If the user has a desktop browser, then he can control the character by pressing the arrowkeys. But if he has a tablet or mobile, then arrowkeys aren't available.

I saw somewhere a controller, which looks like a joystick from the top view. Are there any library for this, or I have to write it myself?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Check the [kineticJS library](http://kineticjs.com/). It is a good option.

Comment: It appears kineticJS is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following libraries: [DHTMLX Touch](http://www.dhtmlx.com/touch/), [TouchScroll](http://uxebu.com/blog/2010/04/27/touchscroll-a-scrolling-layer-for-webkit-mobile/), [XUI](http://code.google.com/p/xui-js/), [SLY](http://github.com/digitarald/sly), [jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/), [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: I know, how to handle touch events. I'm just  looking for a library, using I can create a controller like in this picture: http://cdn.chriswrites.com/wp-content/uploads/Minecraft-Pocket-Edition-1.jpg?bb7ee4

Comment: Ok, but I think there is no library for this purpose. You can create you own controller, it's easy with any of the above libraries

Answer (score 0):

Yes many libraries are available to be used 
You can use Hammer.js 
http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/

Comment: I'm just  looking for a library, using I can create a controller like in this picture: http://cdn.chriswrites.com/wp-content/uploads/Minecraft-Pocket-Edition-1.jpg?bb7ee4

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem last month, so I decided to create an opensource library for this task.
If you want to contribute let me know.

https://github.com/qbolec/Joydiv

Currently it is testd on Samsung Galaxy Tab and my Laptop;)